# JDBC, MySQL: getting back row data from PreparedStatement executes

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using the following setup:

```
public MySQLProcessWriter(Connection con) throws SQLException { 
 String returnNames[] = {"processId","length","vertices"};
 addresser = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO addressbook (length, vertices, activity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", returnNames);
}
```

`processId` corresponds to an auto-incrementing column in the addressbook table.  So the idea is: I have a repeated insert, I get back some of what was inserted + the auto-generated processId.  However, I'm getting a "column not found" SQLException when I attempt to `addresser.getGeneratedKeys().getInt("processId");` after executing the prepared statement (after the appropriate setting of values).  The code for that is

```
addresser.setInt(1, length);
addresser.setInt(2, vertices);
addresser.setDouble(3, activity);
addresser.executeUpdate();
int processId = addresser.getGeneratedKeys().getInt("processId");
```

inside a loop that is updating length, vertices, activity.  So...what gives?  Am I misunderstanding what the prepareStatement(sqlstring, string[]) method does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call next() on the returned result set

```
ResultSet keys = addresser.getGeneratedKeys();
int processId = -1;
if (keys.next())
{
  processId = keys.getInt("processId");
}
```

Comment: well.. I guess I wasn't first... looks like we are both probably correct then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `next()` method on `ResultSet` returned from `getGeneratedKeys()` prior to calling `getInt()`

```
ResultSet rs = addresser.getGeneratedKeys();
int processId = 0;
if (rs.next()) {
  processId = rs.getInt("processId");
}
```